# ctags support for moops

Tags: perl, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags, moops

[Moops](http://search.cpan.org/~tobyink/Moops-0.030/lib/Moops.pm) enhances the perl syntax by constructs such as:

```perl
class MyPkg::MyClass {
   # ...
}
```

and adds the possibility to declare signatures for member functions by introducing the new keywords `fun` and `method`:

```perl
class MyPkg::MyClass {
    method run(ArrayRef $ar){
    }
 }
```

I use vim and tag files to navigate my code base, but those new keywords are unknown to `ctags`, so classes, functions and methods are not indexed. How can I improve the situation?

Answer (score 6):

I can add regular expressions to ctags extending the built-in perl language like so:

```
$ ctags \
--regex-Perl="/^[ \t]*method\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1/s/" \
--regex-Perl="/^\s*class\s+([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)/\1/p/" \
-R .
```

or I can put them in my `~/.ctags` file (omitting the quotes)

Assuming we have a small project:

```
$ tree
.
├── MyPkg
│   ├── MyClass.pm
│   └── MyOtherClass.pm
└── myscript.pl
```

With `MyPkg/MyClass.pm`:

```perl
use Moops;

class MyPkg::MyClass {
  method run( ArrayRef $args ){
  }
}
```

and `MyPkg/MyOtherClass.pm`:

```perl
use Moops;
package MyPkg;

class MyOtherClass {
  method run( ArrayRef $args ){
  }
}
```

Note the alternate syntax here. The package name gets prepended to the class name resulting in `MyPkg::MyOtherClass`.

Finally, `myscript.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use MyPkg::MyClass;
use MyPkg::MyOtherClass;

MyPkg::MyClass->new()->run(\@ARGV);
MyPkg::MyOtherClass->new()->run(\@ARGV);
```

Calling `ctags` with the additional regex definitions mentioned above, the resulting tag file looks like this:

```
MyOtherClass    MyPkg/MyOtherClass.pm   /^class MyOtherClass {$/;"  p
MyPkg   MyPkg/MyOtherClass.pm   /^package MyPkg;$/;"    p
MyPkg::MyClass  MyPkg/MyClass.pm    /^class MyPkg::MyClass {$/;"    p
run MyPkg/MyClass.pm    /^  method run( ArrayRef $args ){$/;"   s
run MyPkg/MyOtherClass.pm   /^  method run( ArrayRef $args ){$/;"   s
```

This almost works:

1. moving the cursor over `MyPkg::MyClass` and pressing `CTRL-]` vim can find the class definition
2. moving the cursor over the first call of `run()` vim finds a definition for the function

But, there are two problems here:

1. in the case of the first call of `run()` vim cannot unambigously decide which function is called, as it lacks context; you have to decide for yourself (using `:ts`)
2. moving the cursor over `MyPkg::MyOtherClass` vim cannot find a tag at all

So, in conclusion, my best practise for `Moops`, `vim` and `ctags` would be to always declare classes fully qualified.

Comment: Hi, when I run ctags on the command line I get command not found. I installed it, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Could you give an example of what it looks like in the ~/.ctags file?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!

I find that very useful with other syntax-sugar libraries (i.e.Function::Parameters), although a bit improved regex for method finding:

`--regex-Perl="/^[ \t]*method\s+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\1/s/"`